# Getting Large System Preview Image like in Finder

Tags: cocoa, image, finder

So, I am working on an app that displays some info about the current computer, and I want it to be quite Finder-like. When you do Get Info on your computer in Finder, there is a preview section with a large icon of your computer. I want to be able to get these in my code. For example, I have the Mid-2010 MacBook. Doing a bit of searching, it turned out that icon is present in `/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Resources/com.apple.macbook-unibody-plastic.icns`

I am able to get the system model, and I suppose Finder does that and has some sort of mapping to map the system model to the correct image. Does anyone know where this sort of mapping is located, or how I could replicate this effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very easy:

```
NSImage *computerIcon = [NSImage imageNamed:NSImageNameComputer];
```

The resulting image has multiple sizes (`NSImageRep`s). Depending on where you draw it, the right size should be chosen automatically. To access a specific size (like the 512x512) version, you could do something like:

```
NSImageRep *largeRep = [computerIcon bestRepresentationForRect:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 512, 512) context:nil hints:nil];
```

Comment: That gives me the small, small 32x32 pixel looking icon. I mean the large 512x512 icons that finder shows. Like here in finder: http://cl.ly/0P0S1l1C1u3G1Q2p1e1I

Comment: No, the image has multiple sizes (just like an .icns file). I've edited my answer to clarify.

Comment: Never mind, it turned out that I just have to scale it up to have it show the correct size. This wasn't documented anywhere, so I figured I had to make it more complicated than I have to.

Comment: This comes from NSImage being resolution-independent. NSImage doesn't even necessarily represent a bitmap (vector formats are supported too). Can be confusing at times though.